# How to change the value of a reported column from a data source Reportviewer

Tags: c#, vb.net, reportviewer

I have vb.net program that I'm looking to report Time Clock exceptions.  I want to change the Value of a column inside vb.net  If the Value is less than "0" then I want it to report "0" if it is > 0 then I want to report it's actual value.  Is there a way to modify the reported value in that way inside report viewer or the report.rdlc?

For example, On the .rdlc right now I'm calling for the column this way:

```
=Fields!BreakTime.Value
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
=Fields!BreakTime.Value < 0 Then "0" else =Fields!Breaktime.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the iIF Function.

```
=IIF(Fields!BreakTime.Value < 0, "0", Fields!BreakTime.Value)
```